# I want to remove polyline on google map(Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I'm creating the app using google map API. The app draws user's steps on google map. I did success to drawing user's step in real-time.
 A button is used to stop drawing line. So, insult method in onClickListener.
This is my code

```
    private GoogleMap map;
    private PolylineOptions polylineOptions;
    private Polyline polyline;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private myLocation mylocation = new myLocation();

    private Button btn_clear, btn_start;

    private ArrayList<LatLng> testArray = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,mylocation);
                return;
            }
        });
        btn_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);
        btn_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                polyline.remove();
                map.clear();
                locationManager.removeUpdates(mylocation);
                Intent intent = new Intent(TEST.this, WalkResult.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    }

    public class myLocation implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            LatLng spot = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            testArray.add(spot);

            polyline = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions
            .add(testArray.get(0))
            .color(Color.DKGRAY));

            Log.d("Insult", "testArray : " + testArray.get(0));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(spot, 17));
            map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

            testArray.remove(0);
        }
```

However, Polyline.remove is doesn't removing line. I don't understand that why polyline didn't erase.
 So, I use 'polyline.getPoints' in 'LocationListener' to find reason. This is result.

```
04-04 10:10:48.885 10661-10661/kr.co.wdream D/Removing?: polyline : [lat/lng: (37.4851513,126.8986154)]
04-04 10:10:57.695 10661-10661/kr.co.wdream D/Removing?: polyline : [lat/lng: (37.4851513,126.8986154), lat/lng: (37.4851387,126.8985779)]
```

```
04-04 10:11:30.325 10661-10661/kr.co.wdream D/Removing?: polyline : [lat/lng: (37.4851513,126.8986154), lat/lng: (37.4851387,126.8985779), lat/lng: (37.4851357,126.8985547), lat/lng: (37.4851495,126.8986224)]
```

Is it right?
How can i do ? Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solve this problem. I don't think that this is good answer, but It's work.
I use 'finish()' method after 'startActivity'. And when return this activity(map activity), using startActivity, restart activity.
All polyline's Points removed. Thanks